# how to find $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_0^x f(x,t)dt\right)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know how to compute $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_0^x f(t)\,dt\right)$. This is simply equal to $f(x)$.

I also know how to compute $\frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_0^a f(x,t)\,dt\right)$. We first compute the integral, taking $x$ as constant, and then we take the derivative w.r.t. $x$.

**However, what if there is an $x$ both *inside* the integrand, and in one of its *interval bounds*, as follows:**

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \int_0^x f(x,t)\,dt\right)$$

**How then do we integrate this?**

Comment: Leibnitz's rule. - Differentiation Under the Integral Sign

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac d {dx} \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ is NOT "simply equal to $f(t)$"; rather it is $f(x). \qquad$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Define $u(x,y) := \int_0^x f(y,t) dt$. 
   Then

   a.  $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = f(y,x)$, by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,  and

   b.  $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \int_0^x \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}f(y,t) dt$, by differentiation under integral sign.
2. Assume $y=y(x)$ and use chain rule: 
   $\frac{d}{dx} u(x,y(x)) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}  \times \frac{dy}{dx}$.